# Ajax request with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a dropdown list.Value of dropdown list is EventID and text is EventName. I want to get events according to eventID. Event should come as json format. I want to make an ajax request and get event as json format but i dont know how to make ajax request. I am using MVC. That is my dropdown list html;

```
 <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="eventname">@(PageResources.event_)</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select name="EventID" id="eventID" class="input-xlarge">
                            @foreach (var item in eventList)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.UserEvent.EventID">@item.UserEvent.EventID-@item.UserEvent.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EventID) &nbsp </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
$("#eventID").change(function () {



        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar like this, the data being returned was a json array of objects that had an id and name, which i used to populate the second dropdown.

```
    $("#MyFirstDropdown").on("change", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MyUrl',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { ID: $(this).val() }, //Passing over the the value selected, the action result is expecting and ID parameter passed to it
            success: function (data) {
                //Clear out the previous elements added
                var domContinents = $("#MyOtherDropdown").get(0);
                for (var i = domContinents.options.length; i >= 0; i--) {
                    domContinents.remove(i);
                }

                //Add new elements from request
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var item = data[i];
                    var opt = new Option(item.Name, item.Id);
                    $("#MyOtherDropdown").append(opt);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```